# Add left/right digits after and before certain character in SQL

Tags: sql

I got the following entry in my database:

```
1;3000;30;20;20;20;30000;30;21;3
```

I want to add all first digits to the left of `;` and all first digits to the right of `;` so (in this case) it displays `2;23` which is `(1+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+1);(3+3+2+2+2+3+3+2+3)`

Please note that the number of characters (;) may vary but it is always the same character.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What database are you using? Mysql, Sql Server, Postgres, Oracle, ... ?  Also... yuck.

Comment: hahaha, that made my day...ROFL

Comment: I know it's a longshot, but I'm rooting for Teradata here since it has a very handy `strtok_split_to_table` function that combined with `substring()` and `xml_agg()` would take care of this toot-sweet.

Comment: how did 2 become (1+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+1)?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to get what you need:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCounts 
(
    @stringToSplit varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sumDigitsBefore int = 0, @sumDigitsAfter int = 0, @currentIndex int = 0

    select @currentIndex = charindex(';', @stringToSplit)

    while @currentIndex > 0
    begin

        if @currentIndex > 1
        begin
            select @sumDigitsBefore = @sumDigitsBefore + cast(substring(@stringToSplit, @currentIndex - 1, 1) as int)
        end

        if @currentIndex < len(@stringToSplit)
        begin
            select @sumDigitsAfter = @sumDigitsAfter + cast(substring(@stringToSplit, @currentIndex + 1, 1) as int)
        end

        select @currentIndex = charindex(';', @stringToSplit, @currentIndex + 1)

    end

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN cast(@sumDigitsBefore as varchar(max)) + ';' + cast(@sumDigitsAfter as varchar(max))

END
GO
```